# how to check image manifest in containerd?

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, docker-image, containerd

In docker, we can use

```
docker manifest inspect
```

to check the image manifest.

For nerdctl and ctr\crictl, there is no manifest related commands.

nerdctl image inspect only shows some basic information about the image.

Answer (score 2):

1. check sha of the image by `nerdctl inspect`

```
        "Id": "sha256:221177c6082a88ea4f6240ab2450d540955ac6f4d5454f0e15751b653ebda165",
        "RepoTags": [
            "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.7"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "k8s.gcr.io/pause@sha256:bb6ed397957e9ca7c65ada0db5c5d1c707c9c8afc80a94acbe69f3ae76988f0c"
        ],
```

2. check RepoDigests sha and cat the file

```
 find / -name bb6ed397957e9ca7c65ada0db5c5d1c707c9c8afc80a94acbe69f3ae76988f0c
/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/blobs/sha256/bb6ed397957e9ca7c65ada0db5c5d1c707c9c8afc80a94acbe69f3ae76988f0c

[root@paco ~]# cat /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/blobs/sha256/bb6ed397957e9ca7c65ada0db5c5d1c707c9c8afc80a94acbe69f3ae76988f0c
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 526,
         "digest": "sha256:f81611a21cf91214c1ea751c5b525931a0e2ebabe62b3937b6158039ff6f922d",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 526,
         "digest": "sha256:be47ea44f3699337ec9aced948758293f76336bba0900d383623d85c4a88e2d4",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm",
            "os": "linux",
            "variant": "v7"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 526,
         "digest": "sha256:daff8f62d8a9446b88b0806d7f2bece15c5182b4bd9a327597ecde60cf19efb1",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm64",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 526,
         "digest": "sha256:2524e66c23cb024134ec213032437b0af1d239de37f70ab6064e1d31be62da61",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "ppc64le",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 526,
         "digest": "sha256:779c511730521a030b80471064b9a2b4f531575144574882148bf25716031a0f",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "s390x",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 1158,
         "digest": "sha256:778127f16f3d75c810f1928dc6bb474eb22b55ff6e0d703eaff251faa8ab5eec",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "windows",
            "os.version": "10.0.17763.2686"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 1158,
         "digest": "sha256:54cd03c37f2e87826e4c7f1baf500ac6e70fa5fcebadd6254789c80f9268a2f0",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "windows",
            "os.version": "10.0.19042.1586"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 1158,
         "digest": "sha256:85cfebc79dccc7a0e56680778a614b29a0b1c2ae98d4b1efc746764c04d5656c",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "windows",
            "os.version": "10.0.20348.587"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

To summarize, you can go direct to `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/blobs/sha256/` to find the manifest on your node.